# Relative URLS and Apache Virtual Hosts question

Tags: url, codeigniter, apache2

For learning purposes with Codeigniter & php, i am using apache 2.2 on a ubuntu machine.

For img tags and css tags i used relative urls like "/public" (which i store images, js and css files) but since i keep my files at a project based directory eg "/var/www/aproject" directory setting relative to document root src's seems to get only /var/www part.

So i tried setting virtualhosts (i know how to set properly) but it is not working again.

Here is my virtualhost line for this project.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
ServerName project.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/project
</VirtualHost>
```

I setup dns for that servername no problem.

Comment: What part is not working? Have you set up `NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Are your css, js etc in /var/www/public and CI project is in /var/www/aproject?

Comment: @vbence I am using modular configs so NameVirtualHost is set in global config.

Comment: @Ivan It is in /var/www/aproject/public according to firebug my images which gave 404 error has right urls like http://project.local/public/images....

Comment: ahaaa, you are having problem with .htaccess redirecting everything to index.php

Comment: @Ivan Thanks so much editing htaccess solved everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace your .htaccess content with this (I assume everything is directly in public):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|public/.*\.css|public/.*\.js|public/.*\.jpg)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```